# If not now then when - a saying by Hillel the Elder

Tags: meaning, connotation

I'm going to get my first tattoo in English. As English is not my first language, I would like to double-check if this sentence has any bad connotation. I did some research on internet and I didn't find any problem so far.

This is the sentence:

> If not now, then when.

Thanks

Comment: What's considered a bad connotation? I'd consider it somewhat needy (especially as a tattoo).

Comment: I know it is subjective, but I'd like to appeal for common sense. For example, if this sentence is associate to Hitler, it would be a bad connotation for me. Even, if there is a well-know joke about the sentence that I'm not aware will be a bad connotation too...something like that.

Comment: This is the title of a great song by Tracy Chapman. It is about seizing the moment to express your love for someone. I know of no negative connotations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hCoAF2G6wQ

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that phrase (other than that it's a little cliché), but as an aside, I don't think too many English speakers would attribute that saying to Hillel - both because most English speakers don't know who Hillel was (or might think he's the founder of a Jewish university student organization) and because it seems unlikely that Hillel was really the first person to say, "if not now, when?"

Comment: It's all positive. In Hebrew, the word 'then' is implied here, "If not now, when?" as Juhasz has it.

Comment: I would omit then, but use a comma: _If not now, when?_

Comment: If you miss the punctuation, your tattoo will look like ____. Fill in the blank. :)

Comment: Actually, there is a fun way to write this:
https://www.google.com/search?q=if+not+now+then+when&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA796CA796&sxsrf=ACYBGNSguVLccXhK47QX3nWXsoqiIp53qA:1578682039489&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi47rTx2PnmAhWvrVkKHZb4C8MQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1920&bih=1057#imgrc=PNaYk2KnWDmf2M:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression, "If not now, then when?" is most familiar to English speakers as a maxim attributed to the Jewish sage Hillel. An early rendering of Hillel's statement appears in "[The Condition and Belief of the Jews at the Time of the Coming of Christ](https://books.google.com/books?id=PjxKAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA176&dq=%22if+not+now+then+when%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUkKa2wbTmAhVnITQIHX2MAY0Q6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22if%20not%20now%20then%20when%22&f=false)," in *The Biblical Repository and Classical Review* (July 1839):

> Only some particular sayings, characteristic of each [Hillel and Shammai] have come down to us [from the era of Herod]. Thus, Hillel inculcated, as the fundamental principle of Judaism, this maxim: *Love thy neighbor as thyself*. On the necessity of the early prosecution of knowledge, with his accustomed brevity, he said: *Unless I for myself, who will? If I only for myself, what do I become? **If not now, then when?***

The sense of the phrase in Hillel's use seems to be something like an exhortation not to put off the task of self-improvement.

A similar phrase appears in a sermon by Lancelot Andrewes, "[Of Repentance, and Fasting](https://books.google.com/books?id=iONBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA246&dq=%22if+not+now+when%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN4bTFwLTmAhXTHzQIHRfYDq4Q6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22if%20not%20now%20when%22&f=false)," preached before King James at Whitehall on February 26, 1723, in *XCVI Sermons*, second edition (1632):

> And so would hee [St. John] have it, *now* : For, *now* (saith he) *is the axe laid to the root* : *Now* then, or not at all. Nay, not *now* : this is not a *time* ; we have appointed other businesse which we cannot put off. Well, one question more will make an end ; if not at this *time*, at what *time*? **If not *now*, *when*?** But then, this must be set downe, now before we stirre hence ; And so set downe, as if it be not *now*, it be as neere *now*, as may be, for feare *ventura* come not too soone, and take *tree* and *all*. This is sure ; the *sooner*, the *better*, because the more likely ; the *later*, the *worse*, because the less certaine.

Here the call to action appears to be to begin without delay to put one's spiritual life in order, because otherwise the end may come before one is ready for it.

In my view, whether understood as a religious message or as a purely secular one, "If not now, [then] when?" is an assertion about the urgency of prompt action. I do not see it as having intrinsically bad connotations. Rather, it expresses an orientation toward life that advocates action, change, and improvement. You could certainly choose worse sentiments to commit indelibly to your skin.

Comment: The original expression was transmitted through the *Pirkei Avot*; I don't know what time this was first translated into English.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think most English speakers would readily associate the phrase with a bad connotation.

I think the sentence is more readable with a comma and a question mark:

> If not now, then when?

Comment: Agree about the comma, I like it even better without the ***then***:  *If not now, when?*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing question mark in the original! Without a question mark, it's not a question.